# Benchmarking a ruby operation that returns a value

Tags: ruby, closures, benchmarking

The benchmark takes a block and returns the time:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

```
require 'benchmark'
puts Benchmark.measure { "a"*1_000_000 }
```

What if you want to benchmark an operation and get both the return value and the elapsed time?

Or, stated another way, can a closure modify an object passed into it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A closure can modify objects in its scope, like this:

```
require 'benchmark'

a = nil
puts Benchmark.measure { a = "a" * 1_000_000 }
puts a.size

# =>   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.004865)
# => 1000000
```

Comment: So closures have a writable pointer to what is passed to them? And can closures modify @a and @@a as well, assuming those are defined outside of the closure.

Comment: @justingordon: Yes, they can.

Comment: Yuck. I really wish Benchmark would return something like: `[time, result]`. Then you could: `time, a = Benchmark.measure { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

With https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/benchmark_methods

No more code like this:

```
t = Time.now
user.calculate_report
puts Time.now - t
```

Now you can do:

```
benchmark :calculate_report # in class
```

And just call your method

```
user.calculate_report
```